# Error in lambda: No implicit convertion between 

Tags: c#, collections, lambda

I convert one list of  to list  and get error:
**"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between System.Collections.Generic.List and 'void'**

```
return (topics.Select(c => new TopicUi()
{
    Bookmarks = new List<Bookmark>().Add(new Bookmark { Id = c.BookmarkId, Name = c.BookmarkName })
})).ToList();
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Add method of List has a return type of void, this should work for you:

```
return (topics.Select(c => new TopicUi
{
    Bookmarks = new List<Bookmark> {
      new Bookmark { Id = c.BookmarkId, Name = c.BookmarkName }
    }
})).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it is fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

At the very leat, fix this line

`Bookmarks = new List<Bookmark>().Add(new Bookmark { Id = c.BookmarkId, Name = c.BookmarkName })`

`Add` is a void returning method. The line should be

`Bookmarks = new List<Bookmark> { new Bookmark { Id = c.BookmarkId, Name = c.BookmarkName } }`

In order to properly use collection initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling the `Add` method of `List<T>`, you can just use the object initialization syntax:

```
return (topics.Select(c => new TopicUi()
{
    Bookmarks = new List<Bookmark>() 
                  { new Bookmark { Id = c.BookmarkId, Name = c.BookmarkName } }
                )
})).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

`IList.Add` has no return type. Try this;

```
Func<YourCType, IList<Bookmark>> createBookmarkListFunc = (c) => 
{ 
    var list = new List<Bookmark>() { new Bookmark { Id = c.BookmarkId, Name = c.BookmarkName };
    return list;
});
return (topics.Select(c => new TopicUi()
{
    Bookmarks = createListFunc(c)
})).ToList();
```